# CSS does not show up when Deploying MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Hey guys CSS is not showing up to me when I am deploying. I have read everything online. I have tried to put debug="false" which didn't work.

I tried to change my StyleBundle.

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"

                  ));
```

There is a folder that already exists that is /Content
I tried changing StyleBundle to

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css-test").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"

                      ));
```

and then changed @Styles.Render to match that as well, but then the CSS didn't even show up in my Local host.

I've been killing myself over this. If anyone could please help.

Comment: Are you sure that the files are in the destination folder once you deploy? check if you need to mark the files as `Copy as content` in `Properties`.

Comment: See when I open up the files on my server's folder all the CSS files are there. But weirdly when I do inspect element on the site, the CSS updates that I myself made are not showing up?

Comment: Have you tried hitting F5 (Reload/) on your browser and still not get your updated CSS?